# Onclick(this) selecting first element, not current

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

So, I have a list of images like so..

```
<ul class="image-list">
    <li class="image-icon"><a onclick="showImg(this)"><img src="/gallery/latest/1.jpg"/></a></li>
    <li class="image-icon"><a onclick="showImg(this)"><img src="/gallery/latest/2.jpg"/></a></li>
    <li class="image-icon"><a onclick="showImg(this)"><img src="/gallery/latest/3.jpg"/></a></li>
    <li class="image-icon"><a onclick="showImg(this)"><img src="/gallery/latest/4.jpg"/></a></li>
    <li class="image-icon"><a onclick="showImg(this)"><img src="/gallery/latest/5.jpg"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

showImg()...

```
function showImg(img) {
    document.getElementById("photo").innerHTML = "<img src='"+$(img+" img").attr("src")+"'/>";
    $("#photo").slideDown(500);
}
```

The function `showImg()` gets the `src` attr of `this > img` and puts the image in another div. The problem is, `this` is only selecting the first image src. Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe post the jQuery code as well? Your markup is valid.

Comment: You're missing a `>` in the end of the second line btw.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté yeah that somehow happened during copy/paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this` as the context, rather than a contextual selector.

`$("img", img).attr("src")`

Also, you can simplify your code:

```
$("#photo").html('<img src="'+$("img", img).attr("src")+'" />').slideDown(500);
```

Simplified even further thanks to Fabrício Matté:

```
$('#photo').html($('img', img).clone()).hide().slideDown(500);
```

Comment: You can also `clone` the image element, if you're just going to create another element equal to the original one. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DPSsS/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `this` which is an [HTMLAnchorElement] to jQuery

`img+" img"` will probably give you `[HTMLAnchorElement] img`

What you want is

```
$("img", img)
```